# How do I copy values from NSMutableDictionary to a Map?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, stl, llvm

I need to accept NSMutableDictionary  of key value pairs of strings and I need to copy to a stl map. Is there an easy way to do so?
I tried this, but this doesn't work.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setObject:@"10" forKey:@"6"];
    [dictionary setObject:@"10" forKey:@"7"];
    [dictionary setObject:@"10" forKey:@"8"];

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictionary keyEnumerator];
    NSString *key;
    while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        std::string *keyString = new std::string([key UTF8String]);
        std::string *valueString = new std::string([[dictionary objectForKey:key] UTF8String]);
        map[*keyString] = *valueString;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `new` at all? Just pass the results of `-UTF8String` directly to the map, and it will turn them into `std::string`s for you:

```
map[[key UTF8String]] = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] UTF8String];
```

Your existing `new` code is not only useless, but it's also leaking the strings.

---

You should also ditch the `NSEnumerator`. We've had better ways to enumerate a dictionary for a number of years now. Specifically, you could use fast enumeration, or you could use block-based enumeration. The fast enumeration loop looks like:

```
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    map[[key UTF8String]] = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] UTF8String];
}
```

The block-based enumeration will look like this:

```
// if map is a local variable it must be declared with __block
// like __block std::map<std::string,std::string> map;
// If it's static, global, or an instance or member variable, then it's fine as-is
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *value, BOOL *stop){
    map[[key UTF8String]] = [value UTF8String];
}];
```

In this case I would recommend the fast-enumeration loop because it doesn't require modifying the declaration of `map`.

Comment: This is awesome. Can you also comment on how to do the reverse i.e. convert map to NSMutableDictionary? I may have a solution but since I am a beginner in Obj-C, I would really like your input.

Comment: @kunj2aan: Iterate over the map, and convert each `std::string` into an `NSString*` using `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str.c_str()]`.